# Intellij not showing all files in the project folder

Tags: intellij-idea

I have some .log files in the project folder, but Intellij doesn't show them in the Project explorer window. How do I get it to show?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a problem with Intellij not recognising .log files. Adding *.log files to be recognised in Files | Preferences | Editor | File Types solved the problem.